# How to rename AWS VPC Peering Connection through the API?

Tags: amazon-web-services, api, amazon-ec2, vpc

I have an already accepted AWS VPC Peering Connection and I want to rename it through AWS API.

How do I do that ?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer - using [AWS Groups Tagging API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/resourcegroupstagging/latest/APIReference/API_TagResources.html). Example request:

```
{
   "ResourceARNList": [ "arn:aws:ec2:${awsRegion}:${vpc.getOwnerId}:vpc-peering-connection/${vpcPeeringConnectionId}" ],
   "Tags": { 
      "Name" : "MyVpcPeeringConnectionName" 
   }
}
```